# permalink_fu for text fields: How can I convert from blob to string output?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, blob

If I use [permalink_fu](http://github.com/technoweenie/permalink_fu/blob/master/lib/permalink_fu.rb) on a text field I get this for the resulting `permalink`:

```
http://localhost:3000/243webb4ee4ff2227230b4232438591810c35d3f
```

instead of

```
http://localhost:3000/where-is-my-lost-cat
```

I assume this is because the `text` field becomes a `blob` in the database and `permalink_fu` only knows how to operate on `string` fields.

**How could I convert this to a readable `string` version?**

*(without changing the database type from `text` to `string`)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try commenting out [these lines](http://github.com/technoweenie/permalink_fu/blob/master/lib/permalink_fu.rb#L22-23) in your local version. See what the exception is, and trace that to your issue.